# Repetir if novamente quando a validação falha

Tags: python, loop, if

```
ConvInicial = str(input('Você: '))

if ConvInicial == 'Não estou passando bem' or ConvInicial == 'Estou com dor' or ConvInicial == 'Preciso de ajuda':
print('O que você está sentindo?')
RespDor = input('Você: ')
if RespDor == 'Estou com dor de cabeça' or RespDor == 'Dor de cabeça' or RespDor == 'Minha cabeça dói':
    Randomizar = ['Neosaldina', 'Dorflex', 'Advil', 'Tylenol', 'Aspirina', 'Naldecon']
    Randomizar = random.choice(Randomizar)
    print('Você pode usar um {} para aliviar sua dor!'.format(Randomizar))
else:
print('Não entendi, poderia ser mais claro?')
```

Quando o usuário inserir um valor que não está no `if`, ele vai parar no `else`, porém eu gostaria que quando isso acontecesse, recomeçasse novamente o `if` até o usuário inserir um valor correspondente ao que eu programei. O que eu posso fazer para que isso aconteça?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você quer que repita algo deve usar a estrutura de `while`. Então poderia fazer algo assim:

```
ConvInicial = str(input('Você: '))
if ConvInicial == 'Não estou passando bem' or ConvInicial == 'Estou com dor' or ConvInicial == 'Preciso de ajuda':
    while True:
        print('O que você está sentindo?')
        RespDor = input('Você: ')
        if RespDor == 'Estou com dor de cabeça' or RespDor == 'Dor de cabeça' or RespDor == 'Minha cabeça dói':
            Randomizar = random.choice(['Neosaldina', 'Dorflex', 'Advil', 'Tylenol', 'Aspirina', 'Naldecon'])
            print('Você pode usar um {} para aliviar sua dor!'.format(Randomizar))
            break; #para encerrar o laço de repetição
        else:
            print('Não entendi, poderia ser mais claro?')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9EcxlT). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/txituxmx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/LoopValidation.py).

Comment: Obrigado, eu tinha tentando mas estava dando erro, acredito que a indentação estava errada

Answer (score 4):

Eu recomendo você ler a respeito de laços de repetição, for e while. Depois disso procure ler algo a respeito de funções e recursividade.
Isso é uma das bases da programação em muitas linguagens, sem esse conteúdo seu código vai ficar muito limitado.

De qualquer forma, aqui está um exemplo:

```
ConvInicial = str(input('Você: '))

if ConvInicial == 'Não estou passando bem' or ConvInicial == 'Estou com dor' or ConvInicial == 'Preciso de ajuda':
    print('O que você está sentindo?')
    while True:
        RespDor = input('Você: ')
        if RespDor == 'Estou com dor de cabeça' or RespDor == 'Dor de cabeça' or RespDor == 'Minha cabeça dói':
            Randomizar = ['Neosaldina', 'Dorflex', 'Advil', 'Tylenol', 'Aspirina', 'Naldecon']
            Randomizar = random.choice(Randomizar)
            print('Você pode usar um {} para aliviar sua dor!'.format(Randomizar))
            break
        else:
            print('Não entendi, poderia ser mais claro?')
```

Answer (score 2):

Tenho várias considerações quanto ao seu código:

```
ConvInicial = str(input('Você: '))

if ConvInicial == 'Não estou passando bem' or ConvInicial == 'Estou com dor' or ConvInicial == 'Preciso de ajuda':
print('O que você está sentindo?')
RespDor = input('Você: ')
if RespDor == 'Estou com dor de cabeça' or RespDor == 'Dor de cabeça' or RespDor == 'Minha cabeça dói':
    Randomizar = ['Neosaldina', 'Dorflex', 'Advil', 'Tylenol', 'Aspirina', 'Naldecon']
    Randomizar = random.choice(Randomizar)
    print('Você pode usar um {} para aliviar sua dor!'.format(Randomizar))
else:
print('Não entendi, poderia ser mais claro?')
```

São elas:

1. O retorno de `input` sempre é uma *string*, não precisa fazer `str(input())` (Python 3);
2. Ao iniciar o programa, o usuário irá ter que responder "Você" sem conhecer a pergunta, e isso não faz sentido para quem não conhece o programa;
3. Você pode substituir uma cadeia de "ous" numa condição pelo operador `in`;
4. Cuidado com a indentação, ela muda o código completamente se utilizada errada;
5. A partir do Python 3.6, recomenda-se utilizar as *f-string* para interpolação;

Minha solução ficaria parecida com:

```
from random import choice

sentimentos = ['Não estou passando bem', 'Estou com dor', 'Preciso de ajuda']
sintomas = ['Estou com dor de cabeça', 'Dor de cabeça', 'Minha cabeça dói']
remedios = ['Neosaldina', 'Dorflex', 'Advil', 'Tylenol', 'Aspirina', 'Naldecon']

sentimento = input('Como está se sentindo hoje?')

if sentimento in sentimentos:
    sintoma = input('O que está sentindo?')
    if sintoma in sintomas:
        remedio = choice(remedios)
        print(f'Você pode tomar um {remedio} para aliviar sua dor')
    else:
        print('Desculpe-me, mas não sei o que fazer nesses casos')
else:
    print('Desculpe-me, mas não sei o que fazer nesses casos')
```

Adicionando isso dentro de um laço, como pediu, ficaria:

```
from random import choice

sentimentos = ['Não estou passando bem', 'Estou com dor', 'Preciso de ajuda']
sintomas = ['Estou com dor de cabeça', 'Dor de cabeça', 'Minha cabeça dói']
remedios = ['Neosaldina', 'Dorflex', 'Advil', 'Tylenol', 'Aspirina', 'Naldecon']

while True:    
    sentimento = input('Como está se sentindo hoje?')
    if sentimento in sentimentos:
        while True:
            sintoma = input('O que está sentindo?')
            if sintoma in sintomas:
                remedio = choice(remedios)
                print(f'Você pode tomar um {remedio} para aliviar sua dor')
                break
            else:
                print('Desculpe-me, mas não sei o que fazer nesses casos')
        break
    else:
        print('Desculpe-me, mas não sei o que fazer nesses casos')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/UnlawfulLightgreenInternalcommand)</sup>