# Como usar while e if no Python?

Tags: python, loop, while

Me perdoem se é uma pergunta idiota, mas sou iniciante. Tenho que usar a condição while para finalizar o programa. No caso, o código tem que rodar enquanto o peso for diferente de 0. E, caso o peso seja `0`, exibir a mensagem de 'peso inválido' e então, encerra a execução do programa. Podem me ajudar?

```
nome_lutador = str(input('Digite o nome do lutador: '))
peso_lutador = float(input('Digite o peso do lutador: '))
categoria = 0

if peso_lutador < 65:
    categoria = 'Pena'
if peso_lutador >= 65 and peso_lutador < 72:
    categoria = 'Leve'
if peso_lutador >= 72 and peso_lutador < 79:
    categoria = 'Ligeiro'
if peso_lutador >= 79 and peso_lutador < 86:
    categoria = 'Meio-medio'
if peso_lutador >= 86 and peso_lutador < 93:
    categoria = 'Medio'
if peso_lutador >= 93 and peso_lutador < 100:
    categoria = 'Meio-pesado'
if peso_lutador >= 100:
    categoria = 'Pesado'
print('O lutador', nome_lutador, 'pesa', peso_lutador,  'kg e se enquadra na categoria', categoria)
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/336185/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/446743/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/446980/101 acho que um desses resolve o problema.

Comment: Só um detalhe que ninguém comentou abaixo, que dá pra simplificar os `if`'s: https://ideone.com/OFFjUM

Answer (score 0):

Existem **duas** boas formas de fazer isso, varia de acordo com o que você quer especificamente.

**1º forma**:

```
peso_lutador = float(input('peso aqui'))

while peso_lutador != 0:
    print(peso_lutador)
    peso_lutador = peso_lutador - 1
else:
    print('Peso invalido.')
```

Neste exemplo você faz a comparação no próprio while, quando o peso do lutador for igual à 0 ele irá parar e printar 'peso invalido'.

**Ou**

**2º forma**:

```
peso_lutador = float(input('peso aqui'))

while True:
    if peso_lutador == 0:
        break # Isso acaba a iteração
        print('Peso invalido.')
        
    print(peso_lutador)
    peso_lutador = peso_lutador - 1
```

Neste exemplo ele executa a verificação **dentro** do while em forma de if, caso o peso se torne 0 em algum momento ele acaba com o while usando o **break**. Note também que neste caso o while é infinito o que acaba com ele é o **break**.

Answer (score 0):

Existe alguns erros no seu código.

O primeiro erro - e talvez o mais importante - é que você precisa envolver o seu código por um laço de repetição. Neste caso, o laço de repetição mais indicado é o **while True**.

O segundo erro é que você não precisa utilizar a função **str()**, pois o retorno da função **input()** já é uma string.

Então, a forma correta do código seria:

```
while True:
    nome_lutador = input('Digite o nome do lutador: ')
    peso_lutador = float(input('Digite o peso do lutador: '))

    if peso_lutador != 0:
        categoria = 0
        if peso_lutador < 65:
            categoria = 'Pena'
        elif 65 <= peso_lutador < 72:
            categoria = 'Leve'
        elif 72 <= peso_lutador < 79:
            categoria = 'Ligeiro'
        elif 79 <= peso_lutador < 86:
            categoria = 'Meio-médio'
        elif 86 <= peso_lutador < 93:
            categoria = 'Médio'
        elif 93 <= peso_lutador < 100:
            categoria = 'Meio-pesado'
        elif peso_lutador >= 100:
            categoria = 'Pesado'

        print(f'O lutador {nome_lutador} pesa {peso_lutador:.1f} Kg e se enquadra na categoria {categoria}')
    else:
        print('Peso Inválido!')
        break
```

Observe que quando o código é executado, devemos digitar o **nome do lutador** e pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Em seguida, devemos digitar o **peso do lutador** e pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Posteriormente o primeiro bloco **if** verificará se o **peso_lutador** é diferente de **0**. Caso positivo, será verificado a categoria do lutador e, em seguida, será exibido tanto os dados do lutador - nome e peso - quanto a categoria do mesmo. Caso negativo, ou seja, o peso é igual a **0**, o programa exibe a mensagem **Peso Inválido** e encerra sua execução.

**OBSERVAÇÃO:** Enquanto o peso digitado for diferente de **0**, o programa exibirá os dados do lutador e solicita os dados de outro lutador. Desse modo, o encerramento do programa só ocorrerá se for digitado o valor **0**.

Answer (score -2):

Assim também resolve o código:

```
while True:
    nome_lutador = input('Digite o nome do lutador: ')
    peso_lutador = float(input('Digite o peso do lutador: '))

    if peso_lutador != 0::
        # Vai ser 'Pena' se for menor que 65
        categoria = 'Pena'

        if peso_lutador >= 65 and peso_lutador < 72:
             categoria = 'Leve'
             print(categoria)
        elif peso_lutador >= 72 and peso_lutador < 79:
            categoria = 'Ligeiro'
            print(categoria)
        elif peso_lutador >= 79 and peso_lutador < 86:
            categoria = 'Meio-medio'
            print(categoria)
        elif peso_lutador >= 86 and peso_lutador < 93:
            categoria = 'Medio'
            print(categoria)
        elif peso_lutador >= 93 and peso_lutador < 100:
            categoria = 'Meio-pesado'
            print(categoria)
        elif peso_lutador >= 100:
            categoria = 'Pesado'
            print(categoria)

        print(
            f'O lutador {nome_lutador} pesa {peso_lutador:.1f}', 
            f'Kg e se enquadra na categoria {categoria}')
    else:
        print('Peso Inválido!')
        break
```

O `if peso_lutador < 65:` acaba por não sendo preciso, porque se passou pelo `if peso_lutador != 0:` a `categoria` já é igual a `'Pena'` na programação cada `if` ou `elif` que você conseguir resolver sem por melhor, que custa desempenho.

Realmente se o usuário digitar um valor negativo vai acabar entrando na categoria `Pena`, então considere  por um `if peso_lutador > 0:` no lugar do `if peso_lutador != 0:`